# Get information about a CREATE TABLE query

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to get information about a CREATE TABLE query like the way EXPLAIN or DESCRIBE works?

OBS: Im using mysql

Comment: This makes no sense. There are no indexes to consider whilst _creating_ a table. And that is what `explain` lists...

Comment: a `create table` does not have an execution plan because there is no query involved.

Comment: `EXPLAIN` has nothing to do with DDL, it's only for `SELECT` query. Performance of DDL queries almost _always_ is out of the issue since such things are usually done once

Comment: its called `show create table table_name` on an existing table

Comment: Just added the answer so that it helps other in future.

Comment: My prob is to find a way to get all the information about a CREATE TABLE query even though the table haven't been created yet. I didn't found out how to do that, so i assume that its not possible

Answer (score 2):

To see the create table structure we can use

```
show create table table_name
```

on an existing table; [details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html).

Here is an example

```
show create table video
```

The output will look like

```
| video | CREATE TABLE `video` (
  `idvideo` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `video_title` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `video_desc` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `video_length` int(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idvideo`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `video_title` (`video_title`,`video_desc`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3254 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Comment: The downvotes are likely for responding to a low quality question. Some feel answering encourages further low quality questions as you can get an answer regardless of how poor your wording and the OP doesn't learn how to phrase and research properly for their next attempt.

Comment: My prob is to find a way to get all the information about a CREATE TABLE query even though the table haven't been created yet